# Make SqlDataSource control invisible at design time

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, design-time

I have several user controls that contain a drop down list, various validation controls, and a SQL Data Source control. I want to know if its possible to make the Data Source control invisible at design time.

When i use these controls to build various forms the datasource controls show up in the design view and take up space and its kind of annoying.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccounts" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsAccounts" 
    DataTextField="name" DataValueField="accountId" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="NOT SET">- Select an account -</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAccounts" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="ddlAccounts" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="!" InitialValue="NOT SET" ToolTip="You must select an account."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsAccounts" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySqlConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    SelectCommand="AccountSelector_Select">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you can add it programmatically through code behind and then you won't see it in the designer.

```
SqlDataSource s = new SqlDataSource();
s.ID = "mySqlSourceControl";
Page.Controls.Add(s); 

s.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
s.SelectCommand = "AccountSelector_Select";
s.SelectCommandType = "StoredProcedure";

s.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this approach even more controls into span:

```
<span style="display: none;" id="obsPopUp" runat="server"> 
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MySqlDataSource" runat="server"  ...> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource> 
</span>
```

And in Load event change propery of span:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    obsPopUp.Attributes("style") = "display: inherits;"
End Sub
```

It works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to take advantage of the designer tools, wrapping it in a display:none span seems to work well:

```
<span style="display: none;">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MySqlDataSource" runat="server" 
      ...>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</span>
```

Comment: Or more generally - declare a class called alwaysHidden and assign it to all the components that are not supposed to be shown. It's easier to locate them in the DOM later.